# FileWatchdog mechanism in Rails3 ? How to monitor file changes in a directory in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, watchdog

I am new to Ruby and Rails.

For my app I need to monitor a file. If that file changes,I need to execute some code or javascriptto do something for me.

Please help,

Answer (score 1):

You can try this gem: [Filewatcher](https://github.com/thomasfl/filewatcher)

Comment: FileWatcher is working fine.  However, when I tried using the following code in an initialer file. Then my rails application hangs(does not start).
`
**filewatch.rb**   

require 'filewatcher'   
FileWatcher.new(["lib/", "Rakefile"]).watch do |filename|   
  puts "Updated " + filename   
end   
`
Any other way ??